# Change default payment Uber?

Tags: iphone, apple-pay

Whenever I request a ride it defaults to Apple Pay so I have to change it to my card. I don't see a way to make it so that it defaults to my card every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a business profile it will then create a personal profile as well, both profiles allow you to select a default card!